Convergence of infinite series $\frac{(-1)^k\ln(\ln k)}{\sqrt{\ln k}}$
$$\sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\ln(\ln k)}{\sqrt{\ln k}}$$
I want to check the conditional convergence of this series. I have already verified that it does not converge absolutely, but I am unsure whether the series itself converges. Since $\frac{\ln(\ln k)}{\sqrt{\ln k}}$ is not a decreasing function, I cannot apply the Dirichlet test.
Could you suggest a criterion or method to determine the convergence of this series? Thank you!

Why do you think $\frac{\ln (\ln k)}{(\ln k)^{1/2}}$ is not decreasing at least for $k$ large

@Conrad the derivative of that function bigger than 0.. I'am wrong?

See answer below

You can apply the Dirichlet test since $\frac{\ln(\ln{k})}{\sqrt{\ln{k}}}$ is eventually decreasing, and the first finitely many terms do not affect convergence. Indeed, for $x > 0$,
$$(\frac{\ln{x}}{\sqrt{x}})’ = \frac{\frac{1}{x} \cdot \sqrt{x} - \ln{x} \cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}}{x} = \frac{2 - \ln{x}}{2x\sqrt{x}}$$
which is strictly smaller than $0$ when $\ln{x} > 2$, i.e., when $x > e^2$. Thus, $\frac{\ln{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$ is decreasing when $x > e^2$, so $\frac{\ln(\ln{k})}{\sqrt{\ln{k}}}$ is decreasing when $\ln{k} > e^2$, i.e., when $k > e^{e^2}$. Now just observe that,
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\ln(\ln{k})}{\sqrt{\ln{k}}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln{x}}{\sqrt{x}} = 0$$
where the final limit can be shown using L’Hôpital. By Dirichlet test, the series converges.

I'm understand. Really Thank you..!!!!!
